# Access to GitHub Deployments Dashboard

Tags: github, deployment, continuous-integration

Good morning!
I have been playing around with GitHub Actions to build and deploy to multiple stages. Works like a charm.
But deployments in GitHub has been hard to overview.

I have access to Environments, which is where I’ve added some secrets.

I found this article in the docs, but I can’t find it in my public repo. https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/viewing-deployment-activity-for-your-repository#viewing-the-deployments-dashboard

Does anyone know how GigHub deployments work and how to start using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Github Deployments" is really just an API you can use to alert Github about deployments (start/finish) and the Deployments Dashboard to view activity. In order for anything to show up there you first need to actually trigger a Github deployment event and specify an environment. Put the action I've linked below at the start and then end of your existing deployment automation in Github Actions and you should start seeing something show up.

Deployment Action
https://github.com/bobheadxi/deployments

You should probably give this a read through as well, goes into details on where the Github Deployments API fits into things.
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#deployments